# Django navigation as POST input for dynamcial view

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am building an django app that displays real estate data of different cities. The city info is saved in the django model. I have one view that displays all data of a particular city, I only need a way to get the user input of which city data he wants to see.

In the navbar are the names of the cities, how do I save the user choice in the navigation in the session info and use it as input for the view?

In a form of a POST?

base.html

```
   <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="title">City 1</span>
                    </option>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="title">City 2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="title">City 3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="title">City 4</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get request to the views when one of the option is clicked. For example:

In the base.html navigtion section, your list item will be like

```
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'get-city-data' city=city2 %}">
        <span class="title">City 2</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

so your urls.py be something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your existing urls
    path('get-city-data/<str:city>/', get_city_data, name='get-city-data'),
]
```

And views be like

```
def get_city_data(request, city=None):
    # your logic here to return data filter by city
    context = {} # populate with required context
    return render(request, 'city.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried your solution but I get the following error: Reverse for 'get-city-data' with keyword arguments '{'city': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['get\\-city\\-data/(?P<city_name>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']          I am probably missing some piece of code in the view function?

Comment: I dont get an error if I write     <a href="{% url 'get-city-data'city2 %}"> instead of city=city2 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new View like **/city/str:cityname,** get the info about city and use your existing template that render details about city.

in your **base.html**, you can put the href like this **city/City1**. It should make the get request to this view **/city/str:cityname**.